# JPQL: Select objects where attribute can be null

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee-6, jpql

This is my entity definition:

```
@EmbeddedId
private TeacherPK id;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Exam
@OneToMany(mappedBy="teacher", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Exam> exams;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Subject
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="fkSubject", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Subject subject;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Professor
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="fkProfessor1", referencedColumnName = "idProfessor", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Professor professor1;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Professor
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="fkProfessor2", referencedColumnName = "idProfessor")
private Professor professor2;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Professor
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="fkProfessor3", referencedColumnName = "idProfessor")
private Professor professor3;
```

Now I want to get all teachers that have either professor1.id, professor2.id or professor3.id equal to specified id:

```
public List<Teacher> getTeacherByProfessor(Professor professor) {
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT teacher FROM Teacher teacher WHERE teacher.professor1.idProfessor=:idProfessor OR " +
            "(teacher.professor2 IS NOT NULL AND teacher.professor2.idProfessor=:idProfessor) OR (teacher.professor3 IS NOT NULL AND teacher.professor3.idProfessor=:idProfessor)");
    query.setParameter("idProfessor", professor.getIdProfessor());

    return (List<Teacher>) query.getResultList();
}
```

But when I execute this method I get only objects which have all the three professors defined. If professor3 is null, then that object is not included in the result. As you can see from the entity definition, only professor1 can not be NULL.

**EDIT:**

Basically I want to do this SQL statement with JPQL statement (set 7 for example)

```
SELECT * FROM Teacher WHERE fkProfessor1 = 7 OR fkProfessor2 = 7 OR fkProfessor3 = 7
```

Comment: Can you please provide the SQL query that your JPA implementation is creating out of your JPQL query? You could also try to use the `IN` operator: `:idProfessor IN (teacher.professor1.idProfessor, teacher.professor2.idProfessor, teacher.professor3.idProfessor)`. Moreover you can make it even more easy by referencing the professor directly: `:professor IN (teacher.professor1, teacher.professor2, teacher.professor3)`

Comment: Tried :idProfessor IN (teacher.professor1.idProfessor, teacher.professor2.idProfessor, teacher.professor3.idProfessor), it still only returns rows, that has atleast one idProfessor equal to one of the three specified, but all the three attributes need to defined (not null). I also tried :professor IN (teacher.professor1, teacher.professor2, teacher.professor3), but the result is empty list. How can I provide the SQL query that my JPA implementation is creating out of my JPQL query?

Comment: what JPA provider do you use? Hibernate, EclipseLink, etc?

Comment: I use the default provider that comes with JBOSS AS 7.1.1, that is Hibernate.

Comment: Then add the following property to your `persistence.xml` file: `<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />`